# How to use the Windows Phone SDK Namespaces in my Unity project?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, microsoft

I'm developing a game with Unity and using C# as the language for the scripts.
I want to use the Device Vibration in my Microsoft Phone which is easily available for Windows Phone Development in Visual Studio using the following:

```
using Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification;
```

And then calling the following method:

```
VibrationDevice testVibrationDevice = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
testVibrationDevice.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

The above works perfectly when I'm building a Windows Phone App from visual Studio. However i totally need to integrate the above functionality in my Unity game.

Any suggestions, workarounds, tips or even hacks would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a plugin to use that method directly in Unity.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/wp8-plugins-guide-csharp.html) is how you can create any plugin for Windows Phone in Visual Studio for Unity.

You can write it in both C++ or C#. You will be writing a `Windows Phone Class Library` that will contain your native methods in it. Then you build some `.dll`files and bring those to Unity an put them in Asset>Plugins>WP directory. Then you can access those methods using namespace.

Be careful when selecting `.NET` version for `RealDLL` and `FakeDLL`.

**Tip**: In mobile games single vibration is mostly used. If you really don't need the time spanned vibration you can use [Handheld.Vibrate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.Vibrate.html).